# Spring validation nested objects

Tags: spring, validation

I am using spring validation to validate a nested object. 
By using the pushNestedPath and popNestedPath I am able to
track the errors at different levels of the nested object

I need to convert this validation result , which is in a flat structure , 
into a custom object which can hold the hierarchy of errors in a nested 
object structure.

Let me know if anybody has done like this ?